# How to open webview in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, widget

I iniciant in flutter and I have a daut about "WebView". How to open a "WebView" with a widget "ElevatedButton"?

[image]

**Widget with "ElevatedButton"**

```
 ElevatedButton(
                               onPressed: (){
                                 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> WebViewApp()));
                               },

                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, // Background color
                                ),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Entrar em Contato',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
```

I created a webview class that have with this functions:

**WebView Class:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://www.instagram.com'),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried call the webview class in a widget elevatedButton but do not load the page. However, I expected to a easy solution this problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but occurs this error: "'WebViewState' doesn't conform to the bound 'State<StatefulWidget>' of the type parameter 'T'." And "The method 'loadUrl' isn't defined for the type 'WebViewState'."

Answer (score 1):

To open a WebView in Flutter when a user presses an ElevatedButton, you can use the `webview_flutter` package.

Here are the steps to achieve this:

1. Add the webview_flutter package to your pubspec.yaml file:

```dart
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      webview_flutter: ^2.0.13 # Use the latest version of webview_flutter
```

2. Import the necessary packages in your Dart file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

3. Create a StatefulWidget that will hold your WebView and button:

```dart
class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  final webViewKey = GlobalKey<WebViewState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WebView Example"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Navigate to a URL when the button is pressed
              webViewKey.currentState!.loadUrl("https://example.com");
            },
            child: Text("Open WebView"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: WebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, we create a StatefulWidget called WebViewExample. It contains an ElevatedButton that, when pressed, uses the loadUrl method of the WebView to navigate to a specific URL (in this case, "https://example.com"). The WebView is wrapped in an Expanded widget to take up the remaining space in the column.

4. To use the WebViewExample widget, you can add it to your main.dart file or any other appropriate location in your app:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: WebViewExample(),
  ));
}
```

This is just a general answer, I hope it will help you out!